# Vue: axios executing synchronously instead of asynchronously on multiple components

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to load ajax data when my component is created, however, this seems to make other items that also load via ajax within `created()` load synchronously instead of asynchronously when the following is executed, this ajax request takes about 2 seconds to run causing everything after to load in a synchronous style.

The following component takes about 2 seconds to load from the ajax call:

**component1.vue**

```
export default {
  data: () => {
    return { balance: { chips: 0, coins: 0, rewards: 0 } }
  },
  async created() {
    this.balance = (await axios.get('/api/player/balance')).data
  }
}
```

This component takes less then a second to load from the ajax call:

**component2.vue**

```
export default {
  data: () => {
    return { items: [] }
  },
  async created() {
    this.items = (await axios.get('/api/items')).data
  }
}
```

The two should load asyncronusly, however they do not, `/api/player/balance` runs, then `/api/items` runs.

I have also tried using `.then()` like this as well:

```
export default {
  data: () => {
    return { balance: { chips: 0, coins: 0, rewards: 0 } }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get('/api/player/balance').then(function (response) {
      this.balance = response.data
    })
  }
}
```

When I wrap `this.balance = ...` in a `setTimeout`, then the other items load fine.

Is there a better way to implement this so ajax request to run synchronously?

#### Edit

Using `fetch` solves the issue of request loading synchronously and allows them to load asynchronously.

```
export default {
  data: () => {
    return { balance: { chips: 0, coins: 0, rewards: 0 } }
  },
  async created() {
    let response = await fetch('/api/player/balance')
    this.balance = await response.json()
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with `axios`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried without `await`? The `await` expression causes `async` function execution to pause until  a Promise is fulfilled, that is causing your other items to hang until the ajax call is complete

**EDIT**

Can you try this with your other attempt?

```
axios.get('/api/player/balance').then((response) => {
  this.balance = response.data
});
```

The callback function you used in the `then` part uses ES5 notation where the keyword `this` will be scoped to that method only. moving into a ES6 notation will do. Or you can hold `this` into a new variable and work accordingly with that like this

```
const self = this;
axios.get('/api/player/balance').then(function(response) {
  self.balance = response.data
});
```

Although, the best practice (to me) is to update model in `mounted()` other than `created()`

Comment: You can check this edited version with your newly tried stuff as well

Comment: Moving it to mounted fixes the issue

Comment: however, if I move all into mounted it does the same thing

Comment: Strange! I made it work in `created()` with this dummy api https://jsfiddle.net/Ltyyjnry/1/

Comment: All of my ajax calls work, it is just running them synchronously instead of asynchronously. that is what I mean by `hang`...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, may I know how you layout your component1 and component 2? I created one fiddle in my answer, it seems working fine.

Comment: My question has been updated with two components. component1 has an ajax call that takes about 2 seconds, which is causing component2 to load after component1 has finished, but component2 takes less than 1 second to execute so it should be done before component1, however it is not...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, can't duplicate the issue you met. Can you create one fiddle, or edit my fiddle directly?

Comment: That would be hard to do, because I don't have a way to run an ajax request that takes a long time to load...